# Schedule Microsoft Teams Meeting in connection with Exchange on-premise and Outlook Teams Add-In

Tags: office365, exchange, microsoft-teams, azure-activedirectory

I'm trying to find out if I can utilize the Outlook Teams Add-In to schedule Teams Meetings via Outlook when ONLY Exchange on-prem (no hybrid) is installed and AD accounts are synched to Azure AD.

[This page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/exchange-teams-interact#requirements-to-get-the-most-out-of-microsoft-teams) says:

> The Outlook Teams add-in can be used to schedule a Teams meeting for
> mailboxes hosted in Exchange on-premises. However, scheduling a Teams
> meeting on behalf of another user with Exchange on-premises requires
> Exchange 2013 CU9 and above and the new Exchange OAuth authentication
> protocol. Both delegate and delegator must have a mailbox on Exchange
> on-premises.

Does this mean I don't need hybrid Exchange configured and Exchange version does not matter as long as I only want to use the plugin and not schedule meetings directly within Teams?

Answer (score 0):

> > Users' Exchange mailboxes can be hosted online or on-premises. Integration with on-premises Exchange requires an Exchange hybrid deployment.

According to the article you mentioned above, I'm afraid that you might still need an Exchange hybrid deployment so that you can utilize the Outlook Teams Add-In to schedule Teams Meetings via Outlook.